# Why Ansible failed to ping instance which I can connect?

Tags: ssh, ping, ansible

I can connect my AWS EC2 instance

```
ssh -i "pizdform.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-206-23-6.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Last login: Tue Feb 21 12:36:50 2023 from ...
```

I tried Ansible ping

```
cat test-project/hosts.ini
[web]
52.206.23.6

ansible -i test-project/hosts.ini web -m ping -u ec2-user
```

got failed ping

```
52.206.23.6 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ec2-user@52.206.23.6: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says "permission denied". That tells me that you're not using the proper SSH identity file to connect to your target (the `pizdform.pem` file passed as a parameter to the `-i` option in your bare SSH command). Use the `--private-key PRIVATE_KEY_FILE` option to `ansible` to use the PEM file and you should be able to connect just fine. You can also use `ssh-agent` to store the identity in memory and avoid having to use the `--private-key` option to `ansible`.

Answer (score 0):

I started learning ansible and met this problem recently.
Found a solution that is appending `ansible_user=username` after the hostname in your inventory file.
After this I received the SUCCESS output, hope this works for you.

Comment: Note that the user in the question is using `ansible -u ec2-user`, which would be identical to using `ansible_user=ec2-user` (or, for that matter, setting the environment variable `DEFAULT_REMOTE_USER` to `ec2-user`).  This user's issue is not with specifying the user name (they clearly know what user they want to connect as), but with providing the correct SSH credentials, the `pizdform.pem` file.